# Get state/provice id with API3

Tags: api, import

I wrote an custom contact import script for our NGO. The old contact data only contains valid country / state abbreviation names. For example CH / ZH = Switzerland / Zürich.

When I now want to create a new address over the API I don't see a way to fill out the 'state_province_id' field.

I'm able to get the country id with this syntax:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Country', 'getsingle', array(
        'sequential' => 1,
        'return' => "id",
        'iso_code' => $row["V"],
    ));


if(isset($result["id"])){
   $params["api.address.create"][0]["country_id"] = $result["id"];
}
```

But how can I do the same with the State/Province, since there is no  entity I can choose in the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative way is if you use the table civicrm_state_province and the CRM_Core_DAO Class, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM civicrm_state_province WHERE country_id = %1 AND abbreviation = %2";
$params = array(
  1 => array($countryId, 'Integer'),
  2 => array($abbreviationFromSource, 'String'));
$stateProvinceId = CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery($query, $params);
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no state/Province API you would have to create one? Assuming you put your import script into an extension, this is not very hard to do. Using civix you can do generate:api StateProvince Get and the codes files (which you then have to adjust) will be generated for you. If you want to know more check out http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-AddanAPIfunction

Comment: I have some time pressure right now, but if I find time in the end I will consider to create an extension of my importer.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up just calling the internal method.

```
return CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Core_DAO_StateProvince',
  $state_id,
  'abbreviation'
);
```

Takes advantage of a higher level of abstraction than sql so possibly more future proof, but probably not as future proof as using a designated API.

Still seems like you can't find it in the API, although getOptions looks close https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15919.

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2017, there is a StateProvince API in CiviCRM: see [CRM-19688](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19688).

Answer (score -3):

http://localhost:8080/drupal05122016/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Address&action=getoptions&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"field":"state_province_id","country_id":1101}

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your answer to provide more detail.  As it stands it doesn't really answer the question.